# GTZAN Dataset inaccessible

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Does someone know why GTZAN tensorflow dataset seems to be inaccessible in the last hour?
the direct link http://opihi.cs.uvic.ca/sound/genres.tar.gz seems to be down and downloading through tensorflow_datasets API raises as well a ConnectionError Exception. Is there a way to report this issue somewhere?